# Uploading files with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, heroku, paperclip

As far as I understand [heroku](http://heroku.com) does not allow to store uploaded files for an individual rails app. In their documentation they mention that files can be uploaded to an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) instance.

I currently don't have an S3 account so assuming I just want to start with a proof of concept type of application does it make sense to sign up for such an s3 accounts or are there options (ideally combinable with heroku) to allow me to upload and store files after the app was deployed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon also has a free usage tier for 1 year for newly registered users.

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

So, for a proof of concept application, you can register and use the service. Here is a link to the article about how to use heroku with amazon s3

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3