# Heroku - hosting files and static files for my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to use Heroku for hosting my Ruby on Rails project. It will involve lots of file uploads, mostly images. Can I host and serve that static files on Heroku or is it wiser to use services like Amazon S3. What is Your opinion on that approach ?  What are my options for hosting that static files on Heroku ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading files with heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034498/uploading-files-with-heroku)

Comment: @Brad Werth - Is it possible ti host uploaded files on Heroku ?

Comment: Not really... I think the best you can hope for is a hack like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661395/creating-temporary-files-in-heroku

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, Heroku's "ephemeral filesystem" will not serve as a storage for static uploads. Heroku is an app server, period. You have to plug into data storage elsewhere.

From Heroku's [spec](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Ephemeral filesystem
>
> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, **but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.** For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku is a great option for RoR in my opinion. I have used it personally and ran to the problem that has been mentioned here already (you can't store anything in Heroku's filesystem). I therefore used S3 following this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Hope it helps!

PD: Make sure not to store the S3 credentials on any file, but rather create  variables as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
I used to have them on a file and long story short someone gained access to my Amazon account and my account was billed several thousands of dollars (just from a couple of days). The Amazon staff was kind enough to waive those. Just something to have in mind.

Comment: Had a very similar experience. I upvote because you never know who might be saved from a few stressful days because of this.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, you shouldn't do this with Heroku for the specific reason of ephemeral storage, but to answer your question more broadly storing user-uploaded content on a local filesystem on any host has a few inherent issues:

- You can quickly run out of local storage space on the disk
- You can lose all your user-uploaded content if the hardware crashes / the directory gets deleted / etc.
- Heroku, EC2, Digital Ocean, etc. all provide servers that don't come with any guarantee of persistence (ephemeral storage especially). This means that your instance may shut down at any point, be swapped out, etc.
- You can't scale your application horizontally. The files on one server won't be accessible from another (or dyno, or whatever your provider of choice calls them).

S3, however, is such a widely-used solution because:

- It's incredibly cheap (we store 20 TB of data for something like $500 a month)
- Your uploaded files aren't at risk of disappearing due to hardware failure
- Your uploaded files are decoupled from the application, meaning any server / dyno / whatever could access them.
- You can always publish your S3 buckets into cloud front if you need a CDN without any extra effort.

And certainly many more reasons. The most important thing to remember, is that by storing uploaded content locally on a server, you put yourself in a position where you can't scale horizontally, regardless of how you're hosting your app.

Comment: This answer seems to falsely imply that it is practically possible to host user-uploaded content on Heroku.

Comment: Fair enough, was just trying to answer the question in a less host-specific sense. I'll add the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It it wiser to host files on S3, and actually it is even more wiser to use direct uploads to S3.

You can read the arguments, for example, [here](https://divshot.com/blog/hosting/dont-host-static-sites-on-heroku/).

Main point: Heroku is really, *really* expensive thing.

So you need to save every bit of resources you have. And the only option to store static files on Heroku is having separate dyno running app server for you. And static files don't need app server. So it's just a waste of CPU time (and you should read that as "a waste of a lot of my money").

Also, uploading huge amount of huge files will quickly get you out of memory quota (read that as "will waste even more of my money because I will need to run more dynos"). So it's best to upload files directly to S3.

Heroku is great for hosting your app. Use the tool that best suites the task.

**UPD**. Forgot to tell you – not only you will need separate dyno for static assets, your static assets will die every time this dyno is restarted.

Comment: I agree with you EugZol...argument and only arguments not downvoting. I am sometimes mad.People downvotes without providing any help. And then I must show my frustration here by writing off topic.

Comment: This answer seems to falsely imply that it is practically possible to host user-uploaded content on Heroku.

Comment: @BradWerth Good point. Updated my answer. Thanks! Now you can downvote me, you deserved your right to :D

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I do solve it by adding all my images in my rails app. I then reference the images using their links that might be something like

myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/image1.jpg

I might add the link from the CMS. It might not be the best option, but it works.